# How to Extract words from list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a string `str1` with the following format, and I need to extract all the words starting with "SF-", without duplication.

I tried this:

```
newlist=[]
# Driver code
str1 = '"SF-9632":"schema,names","startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"total":58,"issues","SF-6349","total":70,"SF-6533'
for x in str1:
    if "SF-" in str1:
        newlist.append(x)

print(newlist)
```

The output inside `newlist` is equal to `str1`.

Comment: What *should* end up in `newlist`?

Comment: "str1" is just a string, not a list. First you should convert it to a list of words. You have to define what a word is i. e. which characters delimit words, what characters can be in a word (e. g. can a word contain or only consist of digits?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the `split` operation which breaks your main string `str1` into an array:

```
newlist=[]
# Driver code
str1 = '"SF-9632":"schema,names","startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"total":58,"issues","SF-6349","total":70,"SF-6533'
lstr1 = str1.split("\"")
for x in lstr1:
    if "SF-" in x:
        newlist.append(x)

newlist = list(set(newlist))
print(newlist)
```

Which then outputs:

```
['SF-9632', 'SF-6349', 'SF-6533']
```

Comment: and for getting rid of duplicates we can `newlist=list(set(newlist))`

Comment: @DmitriyNeledva Do you knwo how to "@" someone in an answer? I wanted to reference you for the point, but I cannot ..

Comment: you've referenced me, it's worked